# Project for Elementary Particle Physics Course

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, data-analysis, large-hadron-collider

Good day! Are there any publicly available dataset in the field of particle physics that can be treated as time series? I am hoping to use methods in white noise analysis to somehow determine underlying patterns of a particular particle of interest.

As what you may probably know already, for microscopic quantities, systems do exhibit fluctuations due to nonlinear interactions. On the other hand, as far as dynamical evolution macroscopic quantities are concerned, there could be a possibility that the system of interest could display some regularities, which will in turn tell something more about the system.

My aim is to use methods in white noise analysis. The idea behind is to parametrize the evolution of a fluctuating quantity $x$ by

$x(t) = x_0 +\int_0^{\tau} f(\tau-t)\  h(t) \ \  w(t) dt \\$

Here, $f(\tau-t)h(t)$ modulates the white noise variable $w(t)$. Thus, we can say that  $f(\tau-t)h(t)$ is a memory function. Depending on the system, one can choose a specific $f(\tau-t)$ and $h(t)$. For instance, using

$f(\tau-t) = \sin^{1/2} (\tau-t)\ \text{and}\ h(t) = \sqrt{J_0 (t)}\ \text{where $J_0$ is a Bessel function of the first kind.}$

There are many other forms for the memory function in the book that I looked up, and this idea is often used for time series analysis. Is this even possible? I am also looking at any possible topics involving supersymmetry. I hope to hear some ideas on what to do that can be accomplished within three months. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you need to tell us what aspect in particle physics you want to investigate. The data in particle physics that is produced at, for example, LHC consists of the particles produced in collisions. It is not in the form of a time series.

Comment: @flippiefanus thank you for your concern. You are right that particle physics data are not in time series form, as I have browsed all over the internet and cannot find one. On another note, I wanted to look at some hypothetical particles, specifically on the theory of supersymmetric-particle spectrum or higgsino-like signatures in experiments in this [guide](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/web/viewer.html?file=../reviews/rpp2022-rev-susy-2-experiment.pdf)

Comment: @flippiefanus using white noise analysis with time series data, for instance energy deposition of an unknown or known particle vs time, i can somehow model their masses using some complex functions that i mentioned above and maybe allow some limits for it as well? Is this concept supposed to work this way?